# Getting the following error while connecting to Content porter in 2013 sp1 tridion

Tags: content-porter-2013

We are trying to connect the content porter giving domain name in username as well as without domain name. But its not able to connect.
We tried to login with public ip address as well as with internal ip address on AWS server.
we are using Tridion 2013 SP1

[image]

Comment: Some additional Info : we are using Tridion 2013 SP1

Comment: also, choose correct protocol from dropdown (HTTP, HTTPS), while connecting CMS from CP. because of this the error could occur as well.

Comment: The error message is indicating that the login failed I believe, since your CMS server appears online via the given address (you might want to modify that picture and blank out the public IP address). So I would validate that you can login with the given credentials from the same location that you try Content Porter from, if that does work, check out the IIS log for authentication failures.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more insight by looking at Content Porter log file, Event log on Tridion machine, IIS log, as suggested by Bart and by using HTTP debugger, like Fiddler. I would start with Fiddler, this way you can see if you have 401 error straightaway.

Comment: He is right!
This is generic error, when something unexpected on connection to server is happened. Source error you can find in the "ContentPorter.log" (path to log directory, e.g. place where this file will be created can be set in Settings->Logging tab-> Log files location)